# wireless adapter won't work on old macbookpro (2011) on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, 17.10

Ok, I updated to 17.10 and my wireless driver no longer works.  I guess I should not be surprised since I know that these old macbooks use a broadcom wireless adapter the drivers for which are sometimes not easily found.  `ifconfig` does not see the wireless adapter at all, but `lshw -C Network` actually seems to see it just fine but lists it as `UNCLAIMED`.  I tried following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric) but I'm not able to find any `linux-backports` packages at all.

`lsmod | grep wl` returns nothing. `grep ssb /etc/modprobe.d/*` returns

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf:blacklist ssb
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.

/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf:# wl module from Broadcom conflicts with ssb
/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf:blacklist ssb`

(this is what I get after fixing the problem with `modprobe`)

Does anyone know where I can get this driver for the kernel in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Hm, so I've sort of fixed it: using the modprobe utility `sudo modprobe b43` and then `sudo rfkill unblock all` *does* fix the problem... but weirdly I have to do this every time I reboot.  Anyone know how I can make this solution permanent?

Comment: Edit to include results for `lsmod | grep wl; grep ssb /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Then reboot.  You had the needed modules blacklisted twice in /etc/modprobe.d/

Comment: Worked thanks!  I'm not too sure how this happened. These might have been left over from back when I installed Ubuntu for the very first time, as I remember I had to do a couple of things in `/etc` to get the wireless working, but I certainly don't remember *creating* any conf files.

Answer (score 0):

The file /etc/modules list kernel modules to be loaded at boot.
Modules are listed one per line. So edit it and add `b43`.
Then reboot. `rfkill` and `unblock` should not be needed.

Comment: This isn't working, I'm still getting the same behavior.